# Какие есть хостинги для веб-приложений на python с поддержкой сохранения файлов?

Tags: python, flask, hosting

привет, кто-то пользуется умеренно платными хостингами для веб-приложений на python ? кто на практике знает нормальные хостинги? мне нужно загружать на хостинг изображения из браузеров и не все хостинги это поддерживают. пользуюсь pythonanywhere.com, но там с этим какая-то проблема. а на ‪#heroku‬ вроде вообще нельзя файлы сохранять

Comment: Виртуальный сервер ищите. VPS. Туда можно установить  всё, что угодно.

Comment: digitalocean, например

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [PythonAnywhere](http://pythonanywhere.com). Насколько я помню, там можно хранить что угодно.